# Varnish: Multiple IPs compare to ACL using Tilde

Tags: acl, varnish, varnish-vcl, tilde, x-forwarded-for

What would happen in Varnish if multiple IPs are in an X-Forward-For header which is compared to an ACL using the tilde operator?

Dummy example:

The request has the following HTTP header:

```
X-Forward-For: 160.12.34.56, 10.10.10.10
```

The Varnish config looks like this:

```
acl internal {
    "10.10.10.10"
}

if ((std.ip(req.http.X-Forward.For, "0.0.0.0") ~ internal)){
    # THIS CODE   
}
else {
    # OR THIS CODE
}
```

Which code block is executed?

Also, does the order of the IPs matter in the X-Forward-For header?

Does it change if there are 2 X-Forward-For headers, each with one of the two IPs?

Answer (score 1):

### Will it work?

The short answer to your question is *no*, it won't work.

`std.ip()` expects to receive a single *IP address*, not a collection. The conversion will fail, and the fallback value *(second argument of the function)* will be returned.

Here's a quick test script that illustrates this:

```
vcl 4.0;
import std;

backend default none;

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.x-f = "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8";
    return(synth(200,std.ip(req.http.x-f,"0.0.0.0")));
}
```

This example will return `0.0.0.0`.

### Does X-Forwarded-For need multiple IP addresses?

It does make sense to ask the question if your `X-Forwarded-For` header needs multiple IP addresses.

The idea is to indicate to the origin server what the IP address of the original client was.

In your case there is more than 1 proxy in front of the webserver, so a natural reaction is to chain the IP addresses in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

A better solution would be to figure out what the IP address of the original client was, and set that value in `X-Forwarded-For`.

The best way to get this done is by leveraging the [PROXY protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt), which Varnish supports.

### Leverage the PROXY protocol

The *PROXY* protocol has the capability of transporting the HTTP protocol, but additionally keep track of the connection parameters of the original client.

Varnish supports this and allows you to set an extra listening port that listens for *PROXY* requests.

Here's an example of how you can start `varnishd` with *PROXY* support:

```
varnishd -a :80 -a :8443,PROXY -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
```

As you can see, port `80` is still available for regular *HTTP*, but port `8443` was allocated for *PROXY* support.

If the proxy servers in front of Varnish support *PROXY*, Varnish will take the value from the original client and automatically set `X-Forwarded-For` with that value.

This way you always know who the client was, and you can safely perform your *ACL check*.

> Additionally, there's also a [PROXY module for Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_proxy.html), that can give you information about potential *TLS termination* that took place in front of Varnish.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking through the varnish code and couldn't exactly figure out if it parsed the collection somehow. It is strange that the code which implemented std.ip (vmod_ip : https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/3aac3b67f6b89f087957b1e1cab2807101be17b8/lib/libvmod_std/vmod_std_conversions.c) is calling a function called VSS_ResolveFirst(). Why would they call it ResolveFirst if it can't handle a list?

Comment: @Silver `VSS_ResolveFirst()` actually has nothing to do with lists of IP addresses, but it is a pretty generic resolver function that takes an IP address or hostname. In case a hostname is used that resolves into many IP addresses, this function selects the first one.

I understand your confusion, but the fact that it contains "first" in the name, has nothing to do with your use case unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank for clarifying. Your test also makes it conclusive.

Comment: @Silver Nice to hear, but don't forget what I mentioned about the `PROXY` protocol. It will make sure the right IP address is stored in `X-Forwarded-For` when you have multiple proxies chained to eachother.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that but we actually have other/better solutions in our organisation which I have recommended for our case. It will certainly help others in the future.